# How to declare a function property of a function?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to come up with a TypeScript module declaration for the [uuidv4](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuidv4) module. It basically exports a function, which takes no parameters and returns a UUID as a string. This was easy to implement, like this:

```
declare module 'uuidv4' {
  const uuidv4: () => string;
  export default uuidv4;
}
```

Now, it becomes a little bit trickier, because on the function that is exported there is also another function as a property called `empty`. So you can use it like this:

```
import uuid from 'uuidv4';

console.log(uuid());
console.log(uuid.empty());
```

How do I setup the second one in the module declaration? I tried it with this:

```
declare module 'uuidv4' {
  const uuidv4: () => string;
  uuidv4.empty: () => string;
  export default uuidv4;
}
```

But this doesn't work, since TypeScript complains with

> Property 'empty' does not exist on type '() => string'.

How do I fix this?

Comment: [I think this article is about the same problem.](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2017/04/11/typescript-represent-function-properties/)

Comment: This solution looks pretty inconvenient and labourious. Isn't there an easier way to solve this in TypeScript? I mean it's not *such* an extraordinary style of programming in JavaScript, is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I got it. Actually, once you know how to do it, it is pretty easy:

```
declare module 'uuidv4' {
  const uuidv4: {(): string; empty (): string};
  export default uuidv4;
}
```

And that's it